# What are the intersections of $(x-10)^2+(y-10)^2=6^2$ and $y=-2|x-10|+19$?

Tags: circles, absolute-value

The real intersection between these two equations is about $x=18.39$ and $x=11.81$. However, I keep coming up with imaginary solutions. Please explain how I can solve for those values.

My work so far

$(x-10)^2+(-2|x-10|+9)^2=6^2$

$x^2-20x+100+4|x^2-20x+100|-36|x-10|+81=36$

$4|x^2-20x+100|-36|x-10|=-x^2+20x-64$

Comment: It's much simpler to get rid of the absolute values from the beginning. Consider $x \ge 10$ and $x < 10$ separately.

Comment: This could be easier if you set $a=x-10$ and $b=y-10$ to get $a^2+b^2=6^2$ and $b=-2|a|+9$.  You can then treat the second as either $b=-2a+9$ (so $a^2 +(-2a+9)^2 =6^2$) with $a \ge 0$ or $b=2a+9$ (so $a^2 +(2a+9)^2 =6^2$) with $a \lt 0$, solve theequations and back substitute.  At first glance there may be four pairs of real solutions

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the first expression is a circle centered at $(10,10)$ with radius $6$, and the second expression is V-shaped, with the turning point at (10,19), directly above the circle. Therefore, one can quickly see that there are four intersection points.

These absolute values in $y=-2|x-10|+19$ can make things messy, so why not remove them from the very beginning.

When $x\geq10$, $y=-2x+39$.

When $x<10$, $y=2x-1$.

Then substitute the corresponding expressions for $y$ in $\left(x-10\right)^{2}+\left(y-10\right)^{2}=6^{2}$. Then we are only left with two simple quadratic equations, namely:

$5 x^2-136 x+905=0$ (for $x\geq10$)

$5 x^2-64 x+185=0$ (for $x<10$)

which you can solve anyway you like (complete the square, quadratic formula, with a calculator, etc.)

Finally you get:
$$x=\frac{1}{5} \left(32-3 \sqrt{11}\right)\land y=\frac{1}{5} \left(59-6 \sqrt{11}\right)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{5} \left(68-3 \sqrt{11}\right)\land y=\frac{1}{5} \left(6 \sqrt{11}+59\right)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{5} \left(3 \sqrt{11}+32\right)\land y=\frac{1}{5} \left(6 \sqrt{11}+59\right)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{5} \left(3 \sqrt{11}+68\right)\land y=\frac{1}{5} \left(59-6 \sqrt{11}\right)$$

(Decimal form answer is shown along with the plot.)

And that's it.

[image: Decimal result and Plot with Mathematica]

Comment: Thank you for solving it. I solved this problem a few hours after I posted it and while I did get the same answers, your process of solving it is way easier.